# Spring Boot Web Application using Thymeleaf, when a button is pressed it always returns the else blessing

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

I have a MySQL database table connected to my application with 6 columns, id, user name, ZeusPP, PoseidonPP, HadesPP and AphroditePP. Depending on the amount of "Prayer Points" a user has for the given god they receive a different blessing. This is done using JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>User Sacrifice</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h3>User Details</h3>
  <hr>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Zeus Prayer Points</th>
      <th>Poseidon Prayer Points</th>
      <th>Hades Prayer Points</th>
      <th>Aphrodite Prayer Points</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td th:text="${user.userName}" />
      <td th:text="${user.ZeusPP}" />
      <td th:text="${user.PoseidonPP}" />
      <td th:text="${user.HadesPP}" />
      <td th:text="${user.AphroditePP}" />
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <form method="post" th:action="@{/users/blessing}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" th:value="${user.id}" />
    <button type="submit" name="god" value="Zeus" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Zeus</button>
    <button type="submit" name="god" value="Poseidon" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Poseidon</button>
    <button type="submit" name="god" value="Hades" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Hades</button>
    <button type="submit" name="god" value="Aphrodite" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Aphrodite</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  // Add an event listener to the form
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    // Prevent the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected god from the button that was clicked
    const god = event.submitter.value;

    // Get the value of the corresponding prayer points for the selected god
    const pp = parseInt('${user[god + "PP"]}');


    // Determine the blessing based on the value of the prayer points
    let blessing = '';

    if (god === 'Zeus') {
      if (pp >= 5) {
        blessing = 'You have been blessed by the King of the Gods. You are granted a seat on Olympus!';
      } else if (pp >= 1) {
        blessing = 'The King of the Gods has heard your prayers. May you be granted the power to overcome your challenges.';
      } else {
        blessing = 'How dare you pray to the king of gods without proper sacrifice! *A lightning bolt strikes you down*.';
      }
    } else if (god === 'Poseidon') {
      if (pp >= 5) {
        blessing = 'You have been blessed by the God of the Sea. You can now talk to fish!';
      } else if (pp >= 1) {
        blessing = 'The God of the Sea has heard your prayers. May you be granted the strength to navigate the tides of life.';
      } else {
        blessing = 'How dare you pray to the king of the sea without proper sacrifice! *Tsunami incoming*';
      }
    } else if (god === 'Hades') {
      if (pp >= 5) {
        blessing = 'You have been blessed by the God of the Underworld. You can now create a heavy metal band!';
      } else if (pp >= 1) {
        blessing = 'The God of the Underworld has heard your prayers. May you be granted the courage to face your fears.';
      } else {
        blessing = 'How dare you pray to the king of the dead without proper sacrifice! *You die*';
      }
    } else if (god === 'Aphrodite') {
      if (pp >= 5) {
        blessing = 'You have been blessed by the Goddess of Love. You mother calls and says she loves you';
      } else if (pp >= 1) {
        blessing = 'The Goddess of Love has heard your prayers. May you find love and beauty in the world around you.';
      } else {
        blessing = 'How dare you pray to the queen of love without proper sacrifice! *Divorce papers inbound*';
      }
    }


    // Display the blessing in an alert
    alert(blessing);

    // Send an AJAX request to the server instead of submitting the form
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', event.target.action);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(new FormData(event.target));
  });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the prayer-form html file

Can anyone see an issue with this code that is causing this to happen? In my application I also have a controller class, a Service class, a repository interface and a user class. Also there is other thymeleaf view templates.